# HTML&CSS flexbox

Tags: html, css, html5

CSSでフレキシブルボックスを使ってこのような配置にしたいのですがどうすれば上手く配置できますか？
見にくくてすみません
[image]

```
<article class="main">
      <div class="contents">
        <h1>〇階</h1>
        <div class="room-contents">
          <div class="roomNumber-item1">
            <p>171</p>
          </div>
          <div class="capacity-item2">
            <ul>
              <li>30&#047;60</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="roomTeacher-item3">
            <ul>
              <li>名前</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="facility-item4">
            <ul>
              <li>〇</li>
              <li>〇</li>
              <li>〇</li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="classSymbol-item5">
            <ul>
              <li>クラス</li>
              <li>クラス</li>
              <li>クラス</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

質問者さんの実現したいことは、以下のように行なえると思います。

このコードでは、 `flex-wrap` プロパティで flex アイテムの折り返しを許可したうえで、 `.roomTeacher-item3` を除くすべての flex アイテムに `flex: 1` を適用しています。`.roomTeacher-item3` は、直後に後続の flex アイテムが存在してはならないため、**残りの横幅を `margin-right` プロパティを用いて埋めて**います。

ここで、 `margin-right` プロパティに 100% を設定し、 `min-width` プロパティで最小幅を設定していますが、 `margin-right` プロパティの値を `calc` 関数で計算するようにするのであれば、 `min-width` プロパティを使用する必要はありません。

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.contents {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.room-contents {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.room-contents>div:not(.roomTeacher-item3) {
  height: 40%;
  flex: 1;
}

.roomTeacher-item3 {
  min-width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-right: 100%;
}

.roomNumber-item1 {
  background: #ffa;
}

.capacity-item2 {
  background: #faf;
}

.roomTeacher-item3 {
  background: #faa;
}

.facility-item4 {
  background: #aff;
}

.classSymbol-item5 {
  background: #afa;
}
```

```html
<article class="main">
  <div class="contents">
    <h1>〇階</h1>
    <div class="room-contents">
      <div class="roomNumber-item1">
        <p>171</p>
      </div>
      <div class="capacity-item2">
        <ul>
          <li>30&#047;60</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="roomTeacher-item3">
        <ul>
          <li>名前</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="facility-item4">
        <ul>
          <li>〇</li>
          <li>〇</li>
          <li>〇</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="classSymbol-item5">
        <ul>
          <li>クラス</li>
          <li>クラス</li>
          <li>クラス</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: これって数値弄ったらレイアウトそのままで全体の大きさって変えられますか？もし変えられるならどこを変えたら変わるかも教えていただきたいです

Comment: @user34642 さん > `.room-contents` の `flex` プロパティや、 `.room-contents>div:not(.roomTeacher-item3)`, `.roomTeacher-item3` の `min-width`, `height` プロパティを変更することで、各アイテムの大きさを変更することが出来ます。flex コンテナの親要素の `width`, `height` プロパティを設定することで flex コンテナ全体の大きさを変更することも可能です。